# How to change the color of section of a SVG on click then change back after clicking elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to figure out how to make it so when a user clicks a state on a SVG map of the US (specially [this one](https://codepen.io/TFuego/pen/dydbMVR)) the state changes color. In addition when they click on another state or anywhere else, the color of the previous state goes back to the default.

So far I have functions to change the colors, but not sure how to select the specific states themselves.

```
function ColorChange() {
this.style.fill = "#0A3161";
return false;
}

function RestoreColor() {
this.style.color = "#D3D3D3";
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a class that gets toggled on click.
This class (e.g. ".on") will override the default fill property:

```js
const map = document.querySelector('.svg-states');
const states = map.querySelectorAll('.state');

states.forEach(function(state, i) {
  state.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let current = e.currentTarget;
    // reset all prevously clicked except the current state
    reset_colors(current);
    current.classList.toggle('on');
  })
})

function reset_colors(exclude) {
  const activeStates = map.querySelectorAll('.on');
  activeStates.forEach(function(state, i) {
    if (state !== exclude) {
      state.classList.remove('on');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  height: 90vmin;
}

.state {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.state.on {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 959 593" class="svg-states">
  <title>U.S. States</title>
  <g id="states">

    <path class="state" id="AZ" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M137.7,387.5l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25.1,2.7 l2.5-12.5l3.8-27.2l7-52.9l4.3-31l-24.6-3.7l-27.2-4.6l-33.4-6.3l-2.9,18.1l-0.5,0.5l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1 h-0.9l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7 l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l-0.1,5.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7l-1.5,2.2L137.7,387.5z"></path>
    <path class="state" id="CA" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M136.9,386.8l3.8-0.5l1.5-2l0.7-1.9l-3.2-0.1l-1.1-1.8l0.8-1.7l0-6.2l2.2-1.3l2.7-2.6l0.4-4.9 l1.6-3.5l1.9-2.1l3.3-1.7l1.3-0.7l0.8-1.5l-0.9-0.9l-1-1.5l-0.9-5.3l-2.9-5.2l0.1-2.8l-2.2-3.2l-15-23.2l-19.4-28.7l-22.4-33 l-12.7-19.5l1.8-7.2l6.8-25.9l8.1-31.4l-12.4-3.3l-13.5-3.4l-12.6-4.1l-7.5-2.1l-11.4-3l-7.1-2.4l-1.6,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8 l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5 l2.3,4.8l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6 l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9 l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.8l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2 l2.9,4.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L136.9,386.8z M48.8,337l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1 l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L48.8,337z M50.7,337l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L50.7,337z M71.4,356.8l1.8,2.3 l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V356.8z M70,365.5l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9 s0-2.2,0-2.2L70,365.5z"></path>
    <path class="state" id="CO" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M378.6,256.8l1.4-21.3l-32.1-3.1l-24.5-2.7l-37.3-4.1l-20.7-2.5l-2.6,22.2l-3.2,22.4l-3.8,28 l-1.5,11.1l-0.3,2.8l33.9,3.8l37.7,4.3l32,3.2l16.6,0.8"></path>

    <path class="state" id="ID" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M162.1,181c-22.6-4.3-14.1-2.8-21.1-4.4l4.4-17.5l4.3-17.7l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1 l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.3-4.4l0.4-9.7l3.7-16.5 l4.5-20.8l3.8-13.5l0.8-3.8l13,2.5l-4.2,21.5l2.9,7.7l-1.1,4.6l2,4.6l3.2,1.7l4.5,9.8l2.7,3.8l0.6,1.1l3.4,1.1l0.5,2.5l-6.9,16.8 l0.3,3.3l2.7,2.9l1.9,0.5l4.8-3.6l0.4-0.5l0.2,0.8l0.3,4.1l2.6,12.9l3.5,2.7l0.4,0.8l2.1,2.4l-0.8,2.8l0.7,3.8l1.9,0.9l2.1-1.6 l2.6-0.5l3.4,1.6l2.5-0.6l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.9-2.3l2.5-1.6l0.7,1.7l0.6,2.2l2.3,2.5l-3.8,24l-5.1,29l-4.2-0.3l-8.2-1.5 l-9.8-1.8l-12.2-2.4l-12.5-2.5l-8.5-1.8l-9.3-1.7L162.1,181z"></path>

    <path class="state" id="KS" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M503.4,325.1l-12.6,0.2l-46.1-0.5l-44.6-2.1l-24.6-1.3l4.1-64.7l21.8,0.8l40.5,1.4l44.1,0.5h5.1 l3.2,3.2l2.8,0.2l0.9,1.1v2l-1.8,1.6l-0.5,2.6l2.2,3.6l2.5,3.1l2.5,2l1.1,11.2L503.4,325.1z"></path>

    <path class="state" id="MT" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M356.7,122.3l0.6-11.2l2.3-24.8c0.5-5,1.1-8.5,1.4-15.4l0.9-14.6l-30.7-2.8L302,50l-29.3-4 l-32.3-5.3l-18.4-3.4l-32.7-6.9l-4.5,21.3l3.4,7.5l-1.4,4.6l1.8,4.6l3.2,1.4l4.6,10.8l2.7,3.2l0.5,1.1l3.4,1.1l0.5,2.1l-7.1,17.6 v2.5l2.5,3.2h0.9l4.8-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.2,5.3l2.7,12.6l3,2.5l0.9,0.7l1.8,2.3l-0.5,3.4l0.7,3.4l1.1,0.9l2.3-2.3h2.7l3.2,1.6 l2.5-0.9h4.1l3.7,1.6l2.7-0.5l0.5-3l3-0.7l1.4,1.4l0.5,3.2l1.8,1.4l1.5-11.6l20.7,3l28.2,4l16.6,1.9l31.4,3.5l11,1.5l1.1-15.4 L356.7,122.3z"></path>

    <path class="state" id="ND" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M471.3,127.7l-0.4-7.5l-2-7.3l-1.8-13.6l-0.5-9.8l-2-3.1l-1.6-5.4v-10.3l0.7-3.9l-2.1-5.5 l-28.4-0.6l-18.6-0.6l-26.5-1.3l-24.9-1.9l-1.3,14.2l-1.4,15.1l-2.3,24.9l-0.5,11l56.8,3.8L471.3,127.7z"></path>
    <path class="state" id="NE" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M484.2,247l1.4,2.7l0.1,2.1l2.4,3.7l2.7,3.2h-5l-43.5-0.9l-40.8-0.9l-21.2-1l1.1-21.3l-33.4-2.7 l4.3-44l15.5,1L388,190l17.8,1.1l23.8,1.1l10.7-0.5l2.1,2.3l4.8,3l1.1,0.9l4.3-1.4l3.9-0.5l2.7-0.2l1.8,1.4l5,1.6l3,1.6l0.5,1.6 l0.9,2.1h1.8l0.8,0l1,5.2l2.7,8l1.2,4.6l2.1,3.8l0.5,4.9l1.4,4.3l0.5,6.5"></path>

    <path class="state" id="NM" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M282.7,431l-0.7-6.1l8.6,0.5l29.5,3.1l28.4,1.4l2-22.3l3.7-55.9l1.1-19.4l2,0.3l0-11.1l-32.2-2.4 l-36.9-4.4l-34.5-4.1l-4.2,30.8l-7,53.2l-3.8,26.9l-2,13.3l15.5,2l1.3-10l16.7,2.6L282.7,431z"></path>
    <path class="state" id="NV" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M140.7,177.6l21,4.5l9.7,1.9l9.3,1.8l6.6,1.6l-0.6,5.9l-3.5,17.3l-4.1,20l-1.9,9.7l-2.2,13.3 l-3.2,16.4l-3.5,15.7l-2,10.2l-2.5,16.8l-0.5,1.1l-1.1,2.5l-1.9-0.1l-1.1-2.7l-2.7-0.5l-1.4-1l-2,0.3l-0.9,0.7l-1.3,1.3l-0.4,7 l-0.5,1.7l-0.4,12.1l-1.3,1.7l-1.9-2.3l-14.5-22.7l-19.4-29L89.6,249l-12.4-18.6l1.6-6.6l7-25.9l7.9-31.3l33.6,8.1l13.7,3"></path>

    <path class="state" id="OK" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M375.3,322.6l-10.7-0.5l-6.4-0.5l0.3,0.2l-0.7,10.4l22,1.4l32.1,1.3l-2.3,24.4l-0.5,17.8l0.2,1.6 l4.3,3.7l2.1,1.1l0.7-0.2l0.7-2.1l1.4,1.8h2.1v-1.4l2.7,1.4l-0.5,3.9l4.1,0.2l2.5,1.1l4.1,0.7l2.5,1.8l2.3-2.1l3.4,0.7l2.5,3.4h0.9 v2.3l2.3,0.7l2.3-2.3l1.8,0.7h2.5l0.9,2.5l4.8,1.8l1.4-0.7l1.8-4.1h1.1l1.1,2.1l4.1,0.7l3.7,1.4l3,0.9l1.8-0.9l0.7-2.5h4.3l2.1,0.9 l2.7-2.1h1.1l0.7,1.6h4.1l1.6-2.1l1.8,0.5l2.1,2.5l3.2,1.8l3.2,0.9l1.9,1.1l-0.4-37.2l-1.4-11l-0.2-8.9l-1.4-6.5l-0.8-7.2l-0.1-3.8 l-12.1,0.3l-46.4-0.5l-45-2.1L375.3,322.6z"></path>
    <path class="state" id="OR" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M140.2,176.8l4.3-17.9l4.7-17.9l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5 l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.2-4.5l-13.2-3.7l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6 l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7L99,84l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2h-0.8l-4.3-1.4l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6 l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l-1.3,6l2.7,3.5l6.7,2.3 l11.6,3.3l7.9,2.5l12.4,3.6l13.3,3.6l13.2,3.6"></path>

    <path class="state" id="SD" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M472.8,203.2l-1-1.1l-1.5-3.6l1.8-3.7l1.1-5.6l-2.6-2.1l-0.3-2.7l0.6-3l2.2-0.8l0.3-5.7l-0.1-30.1 l-0.6-3l-4.1-3.6l-1-2v-1.9l1.9-1.3l1.5-1.9l0.2-2.7l-57.4-1.6l-56.2-3.9l-0.8,5.3l-1.6,15.9l-1.3,17.9l-1.6,24.6l16,1l19.6,1.1 l18,1.3l23.8,1.3l10.7-0.8l2.9,2.3l4.3,3l1,0.8l3.5-0.9l4-0.3l2.7-0.1l3.1,1.2l4.5,1.4l3.1,1.8l0.6,1.9l0.9,1.9l0.7-0.5 L472.8,203.2z"></path>

    <path class="state" id="TX" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M357.1,333.4l22.7,1.1l31.1,1.1l-2.3,23.5l-0.3,18.2l0.1,2.1l4.3,3.8l1.7,0.8l1.8,0.3l0.7-1.3 l0.9,0.9l1.7,0.5l1.6-0.7l1.1,0.4l-0.3,3.4l4.3,1l2.7,0.8l4,0.5l2.2,1.8l3.2-1.6l2.8,0.4l2,2.8l1.1,0.3l-0.2,2l3.1,1.2l2.8-1.8 l1.5,0.4l2.4,0.2l0.4,1.9l4.6,2l2.7-0.2l2-4.1h0.3l1.1,1.9l4.4,1l3.3,1.2l3.3,0.8l2.1-0.8l0.8-2.5h3.7l1.9,0.8l3.1-1.6h0.7l0.4,1.1 h4.3l2.4-1.3l1.7,0.3l1.4,1.9l2.9,1.7l3.5,1.1l2.7,1.4l2.4,1.6l3.3-0.9l1.9,1l0.5,10.1l0.3,9.7l0.7,9.5l0.5,4l2.7,4.6l1.1,4.1 l3.9,6.3l0.5,2.9l0.5,1l-0.7,7.5l-2.7,4.4l1,2.9l-0.4,2.5l-0.8,7.3l-1.4,2.7l0.6,4.4l-5.7,1.6l-9.9,4.5l-1,1.9l-2.6,1.9l-2.1,1.5 l-1.3,0.8l-5.7,5.3l-2.7,2.1l-5.3,3.2l-5.7,2.4l-6.3,3.4l-1.8,1.5l-5.8,3.6l-3.4,0.6l-3.9,5.5l-4,0.3l-1,1.9l2.3,1.9l-1.5,5.5 l-1.3,4.5l-1.1,3.9l-0.8,4.5l0.8,2.4l1.8,7l1,6.1l1.8,2.7l-1,1.5l-3.1,1.9l-5.7-3.9l-5.5-1.1l-1.3,0.5l-3.2-0.6l-4.2-3.1l-5.2-1.1 l-7.6-3.4l-2.1-3.9l-1.3-6.5l-3.2-1.9l-0.6-2.3l0.6-0.6l0.3-3.4l-1.3-0.6l-0.6-1l1.3-4.4l-1.6-2.3l-3.2-1.3l-3.4-4.4l-3.6-6.6 l-4.2-2.6l0.2-1.9l-5.3-12.3l-0.8-4.2l-1.8-1.9l-0.2-1.5l-6-5.3l-2.6-3.1v-1.1l-2.6-2.1l-6.8-1.1l-7.4-0.6l-3.1-2.3l-4.5,1.8 l-3.6,1.5l-2.3,3.2l-1,3.7l-4.4,6.1l-2.4,2.4l-2.6-1l-1.8-1.1l-1.9-0.6l-3.9-2.3v-0.6l-1.8-1.9l-5.2-2.1l-7.4-7.8l-2.3-4.7v-8.1 l-3.2-6.5l-0.5-2.7l-1.6-1l-1.1-2.1l-5-2.1l-1.3-1.6l-7.1-7.9l-1.3-3.2l-4.7-2.3l-1.5-4.4l-2.6-2.9l-1.9-0.5l-0.6-4.7l8,0.7l29,2.7 l29.3,1.6l2.3-23.8l3.9-55.6l1.6-18.7l1.4,0 M457.2,567.3l-0.6-7.1l-2.7-7.2l-0.6-7l1.5-8.2l3.3-6.9l3.5-5.4l3.2-3.6l0.6,0.2 l-4.8,6.6l-4.4,6.5l-2,6.6l-0.3,5.2l0.9,6.1l2.6,7.2l0.5,5.2l0.2,1.5L457.2,567.3z"></path>
    <path class="state" id="UT" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M253,309.3l-24.6-3.5l-26.6-4.9l-33.8-6l1.6-9.2l3.2-15.2L176,254l2.2-13.6l1.9-8.9l3.8-20.5 l3.5-17.5l1.1-5.6l12.7,2.3l12,2.1l10.3,1.8l8.3,1.4l3.7,0.5l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9l-2.1,22l-3.2,22.6 l-3.8,27.8l-1.7,11.1L253,309.3z"></path>

    <path class="state" id="WA" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M93.6,6.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.4l-1,3.9l-4.1,13.8l-4.5,20.8 l-3.2,16.1l-0.4,9.4l-13.2-3.9l-15.6-3.4l-13.7,0.6l-1.6-1.5l-5.3,1.9l-4-0.3l-2.7-1.8l-1.6,0.5l-4.2-0.2l-1.9-1.4l-4.8-1.7 l-1.4-0.2l-5-1.3l-1.8,1.5l-5.7-0.3l-4.8-3.8l0.2-0.8l0.1-7.9l-2.1-3.9l-4.1-0.7l-0.4-2.4l-2.5-0.6l-2.9-0.5l-1.8,1l-2.3-2.9 l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6 l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9 l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5V19l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.8l0.3-0.8L93.6,6.4z M84.1,12.3l2-0.2 l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6 l-1.5-2.3L84.1,12.3z"></path>

    <path class="state" id="WY" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M354.3,143.8l-10.5-0.8l-32.1-3.3l-16.2-2.1l-28.3-4.1l-19.9-3l-1.4,11.2l-3.8,24.3l-5.3,30.4 l-1.5,10.5l-1.7,11.9l6.5,0.9l25.9,2.5l20.6,2.3l36.8,4.1l23.8,2.9l4.5-44.2l1.4-25.4L354.3,143.8z"></path>

  </g>

</svg>
```

You can toggle highlighting for each path (clicking multiple times).
Click another state will run `reset_colors(exclude)` to remove previously highlighted state elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target /* || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText*/;   
 
       
 const id = document.getElementById(target.id)
 id.setAttribute("fill","#FF0000")
    
 console.log(target)
});
```

Comment: l don't know if that what are you looking for if not explain more

Comment: Thank you! That's half of it. I also need to have it so when the user clicks on another state, the last one reverts back to the original color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Key is to save the (previous) clicked object in a sensible location.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="45" fill="green" />
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="45" fill="blue" />
</svg>

<script>
  let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
  svg.onclick = (evt) => {
    let previous = svg.previous;
    if (previous) {
        previous.setAttribute("fill", previous.getAttribute("savedfill"));
    }
    let clicked = evt.target;
    clicked.setAttribute("savedfill", clicked.getAttribute("fill"));
    clicked.setAttribute("fill", "gold");
    svg.previous = clicked;
  }
</script>
```